# How can I parameterise the propery of an object for using in crossfilter.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, crossfilter

I am trying to generate a chart using Crossfilter.js, using data that will be passed to the charting method.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
function makeChart(data) {
    var dataCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var chartOrderDim = dataCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.ChartOrder;
    });
    var chartDataGroup = chartOrderDim.group();
    var barChart = dc.barChart("#chartExample2");
}
```

The problem I have is that in this example, I know what the data is that I'm sending to this method, so when I go to create the dimension, I'm returning

```
d.ChartOrder
```

because I know ChartOrder is one of the properties of the data.  So for example, the data is:

```
var data = [
    {ChartId: 1, ChartOrder: 1, ChartName: "Test1"},
    {ChartId: 2, ChartOrder: 2, ChartName: "Test2"},
    {ChartId: 3, ChartOrder: 3, ChartName: "Test3"},
    {ChartId: 4, ChartOrder: 4, ChartName: "Test4"},
    {ChartId: 5, ChartOrder: 3, ChartName: "Test5"},
    {ChartId: 6, ChartOrder: 1, ChartName: "Test6"},
    {ChartId: 7, ChartOrder: 2, ChartName: "Test7"}
    ];
```

My problem is, is there any way to parameterise the d.ChartOrder?  Say I was sending data to this, and I also wanted to tell the dimension which key to return? So for example:

```
function makeChart(data, dimensionProperty) {
    var dataCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var chartOrderDim = dataCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.dimensionProperty;
    });
    var chartDataGroup = chartOrderDim.group();
    var barChart = dc.barChart("#chartExample2");
}
```

How do I make this work?  If I send dimensionProperty as a string with "ChartOrder" value, it doesn't work.  Is there any way to send this function which property of the data that I want it to return from the dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d[dimensionProperty]` to access the dimensionProperty instead of using the dot notation.

You would then pass "ChartOrder" as a string for the second argument to your function that becomes:

```
function makeChart(data, dimensionProperty) {
    var dataCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var chartOrderDim = dataCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d[dimensionProperty];
    });
    var chartDataGroup = chartOrderDim.group();
    var barChart = dc.barChart("#chartExample2");
}
```